# Checking custom code for functional correctness: (ATC FUNCTIONAL_DB)

Tags: abap

Cross-posted on [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3943992):

I am running the functional correctness check across our codebase, but some objects that I believe are functionally incorrect is not being picked up:

I have the following piece of code, that does not use a complete key, and has no order by statement:   But it passes the check:

> Search problematic statements for result of SELECT/OPEN CURSOR without
>   ORDER BY

.  Are there any known issues with the ATC, or is the code below considered functionally correct?

```
select frgco from zmm_rel_codes up to 1 rows  
     into lv_frgco  
     where ekorg  =  lv_ekorg  
       and bsart  =  lv_bsart  
       and knttp  =  lv_knttp  
       and zcap   =  lv_capex  
       and zlimit ge lv_gnetw.  
endselect.
```

[image]

System details:  Netweaver 7.4 SP 8 running on Hana DB.

Comment: It looks like the check in question only applies if you use the *result set* in a way that makes assumptions about the order of the data.   Could there be another check that would be relevant to the code above?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your example select up to 1 row is similar to "select single".
So as the select result is not a table, but a single entry, it does not considered to be an issue.

However, I had to build a custom code inspector check to handle following issues, as standard is not working good there:

1. Select uses “JOIN” or “FOR ALL ENTRIES” statements
   Use “SORT” statement immediately after the select for the key fields.
2. Select without “JOIN” or “FOR ALL ENTRIES”

2.1.    Table key fields are all present in the result (for example, select * is used)
Use “ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY” statement.

2.2.    Only some of the table key fields are present in the select result
Use “ORDER BY” +  statement

Comment: Thanks for your answer Denis.  Yeah I had a similar response from SAP, stating that they run the risk of throwing back too many false positives if they checked for that.  

Having had to QA huge amount of code after this issue I agree with them.  In literally 2 of the 100's of cases where the select was done this way was it actually a problem.

Comment: Out of interest.  How did you do the custom checks?  Did you enhance the code inspector classes, or did you just use the REGEX check?

Comment: Hi Esti, here is the article which will help you to create a new custom check for anything you want :) https://blogs.sap.com/2006/11/02/code-inspector-how-to-create-a-new-check/